# How to deploy multiple instances of the composer-rest-server with enable multiple user mode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

How to deploy multiple instances of composer-rest-server and those instances should be configured to share data. For example, data such as business network cards, Blockchain identities, and REST API authentication settings should be shared so that a REST API client can make a request to any of the instances without having to re-authenticate. Any tutorial link would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial for the REST server is in the [composer documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest).

In terms of multiple instances, they can be started on different machines, or could be started as multiple instances of a container with different ports, or the same port on multiple addresses via Kubernetes or Docker Swarm.